# Optimizing log file size on Ubuntu VM

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, logging, log-files, fail2ban

This is a fact-finding question. I'm implementing `fail2ban` to keep some unscrupulous elements out of my Django website's experience. Note that my webserver is nginx (reverse proxy) with gunicorn as the upstream application server - the machine is an Ubuntu 14.04 VM.

However, my CPU usage right now is going from **~45%** to **~95%** the moment I turn it on (all else equal). At any given point in time, there's lots of activity on my website, and nginx logs fill up quickly. Right now, the current `access.log` is 1.4G in size, whereas `access.log.1` is 850MB in size.

If pertinent, here's a snapshot of the sort of activity in my access.log:

```
31.13.102.111 - - [28/Feb/2016:06:47:22 +0000] "GET /group/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9628 "http://example.com/?iorg_service_id_internal=373234912870626%3B$
31.13.97.97 - - [28/Feb/2016:06:47:22 +0000] "GET /group_list/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9671 "-" "Opera/9.80 (J2ME/MIDP; Opera Mini/4.5.40312/37.7910; U;$
31.13.99.123 - - [28/Feb/2016:06:47:22 +0000] "POST /link/1410516/reply/ HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "http://www.example.com/link/1410516/reply/?iorg_servi$
31.13.110.117 - - [28/Feb/2016:06:47:22 +0000] "GET /link/1410608/reply/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9829 "http://example.com/link/1410608/reply/?iorg_servic$
31.13.97.123 - - [28/Feb/2016:06:47:22 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11979 "http://http-example-com.0.freebasics.com/?ref=mbasic" "Opera/9.80 (J2$
31.13.97.113 - - [28/Feb/2016:06:47:22 +0000] "POST /link/create/ HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "http://example.com/link/create/?iorg_service_id_internal=373$
31.13.110.110 - - [28/Feb/2016:06:47:23 +0000] "GET /group/eb42a653-ec47-43d1-acd7-571646ea3440/private/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11341 "http://example.$
31.13.113.68 - - [28/Feb/2016:06:47:23 +0000] "GET /group/a40cffc5-8194-43a9-8bc9-7517b1cc5ac5/public/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11835 "http://www.exampl$
31.13.99.123 - - [28/Feb/2016:06:47:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12123 "http://example.com/link/create/?iorg_service_id_internal=373234912870$
31.13.102.98 - - [28/Feb/2016:06:47:23 +0000] "POST /vote/ HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "http://example.com/?iorg_service_id_internal=373234912870626%3BAfrI$
31.13.113.76 - - [28/Feb/2016:06:47:24 +0000] "GET /group/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9282 "http://example.com/link/1410354/reply/?iorg_service_id_internal=$
31.13.110.98 - - [28/Feb/2016:06:47:24 +0000] "GET /link/1410807/reply/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11083 "-" "SAMSUNG-SM-B360E Opera/9.80 (J2ME/MIDP; Opera$
31.13.99.111 - - [28/Feb/2016:06:47:24 +0000] "GET /group/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8798 "http://example.com/?iorg_service_id_internal=373234912870626%3BA$
31.13.113.95 - - [28/Feb/2016:06:47:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12181 "http://example.com/?iorg_service_id_internal=373234912870626%3BAfq3H8$
31.13.99.111 - - [28/Feb/2016:06:47:24 +0000] "GET /link/1410516/reply/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9753 "http://www.example.com/link/1410516/reply/?iorg_ser$
141.0.15.221 - - [28/Feb/2016:06:47:24 +0000] "GET /users/Veeraj/unseen/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8556 "http://example.com/link/1381878/reply/" "Opera/9.8$
31.13.110.127 - - [28/Feb/2016:06:47:25 +0000] "GET /group/d81f3a5e-049d-4ceb-abaf-8bc1a571001a/private/ HTTP/1.1" 200 12576 "http://example.$
31.13.110.110 - - [28/Feb/2016:06:47:25 +0000] "GET /users/Pariza/activity/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8233 "http://example.com/users/Pariza/?iorg_service_i$
31.13.97.121 - - [28/Feb/2016:06:47:25 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12094 "http://example.com/link/1410735/reply/?iorg_service_id_internal=37323$
31.13.97.103 - - [28/Feb/2016:06:47:25 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11081 "http://example.com/link/create/?iorg_service_id_internal=373234912870$
31.13.102.120 - - [28/Feb/2016:06:47:26 +0000] "GET /group/1a1cb850-b526-46d3-893b-03e2ad2eeb2b/private/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11934 "http://example.$
31.13.110.100 - - [28/Feb/2016:06:47:26 +0000] "POST /vote/ HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "http://example.com/?iorg_service_id_internal=373234912870626%3BAfr$
31.13.102.111 - - [28/Feb/2016:06:47:27 +0000] "POST /link/1410816/reply/ HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "http://example.com/link/1410816/reply/?iorg_service_$
31.13.97.123 - - [28/Feb/2016:06:47:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12490 "http://http-example-com.0.freebasics.com/" "Opera/9.80 (Android; Oper$
31.13.113.67 - - [28/Feb/2016:06:47:27 +0000] "GET /group/d6be8c59-8d1e-40d4-92f9-55ed0f906ff6/private/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10962 "http://example.p$
66.220.156.113 - - [28/Feb/2016:06:47:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12136 "-" "Nokia110/2.0 (03.04) Profile/MIDP-2.1 Confi
```

`fail2ban` has various jail definitions in it that pertain to my `access.log`. For instance, `nginx-postflood` guards against POST flood and `nginx-getflood` guards against GET flood, parsing `access.log` to see patterns.

My questions are:

1) Why is fail2ban's performance so bad in my current set up? Is it because the entire `access.log` file is moved into the CPU Memory for fail2ban jails to start parsing it?

2) If `access.log` file size is indeed to blame, is there a way I can control this parameter? I would prefer to have several 80MB `access.log` files instead of having big, chunky ones like I do currently. What do I do to set it up that way? Can you give me a concrete example?

Thanks in advance, and ask for more information in case you need it.

Comment: You really will need to tell us what the specs on your VM are.

Comment: Not really an answer, merely for information: there is a feature request open for fail2ban to [read logs from named pipes](https://sourceforge.net/p/fail2ban/feature-requests/69/). When this is implemented it will solve your problem instantly.

Comment: @Iain: It's a Standard DS3 Azure VM, I'm using it standalone for the web application (the database is hosted on a separate VM). Btw, I reset access.log and tested fail2ban on a much smaller file size. Much better performance. I think that answers part (1) of my question.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: read the ticket. I hope they do it, my example is a total case study for why they should!

Comment: How quickly do your logs fill up? How often do you `logrotate` them?

Comment: Also, does the fail2ban CPU load stay high, or does it trail off after, say, half an hour?

Comment: @ParthianShot: Didn't trail off. Logrotation was set to `weekly`, I've set it to `daily` now. Is it possible to do less than `daily`?